# check if all functions are true and then execute modal window

Tags: javascript, validation, modal-dialog

I'm trying to do some form validation which includes checking if a dropdown menu isn't left blank, checking that all input areas are not left blank and validating the email field. I have functions that will return true/false depending on the input.
What I am trying to do now is check all of my validation functions in a single function, and if true I want to open a modal window.
All of my validation functions are returning true(as expected, this works fine) but my nested function is returning false?

```
function checkAll() {
    if (ValidateEmail() && checkIfEmpty() && checkDrop()) {
        console.log(true);
    } else {
        console.log(false);
    }
}

function checkDrop() {
    if ($("#hospitals").val() == null) {
        console.log(false);
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log(true);
        return true;
    }
}
function ValidateEmail() {
    if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(form1.email.value)) {
        console.log(true);
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log(false);
        return false;
    }
}

function checkIfEmpty() {
    $('#form1 input').each(function () {
        if (!$.trim(this.value).length) {
            console.log(false);
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `checkIfEmpty` function has no return

inside you have a `$('#form1 input').each(function(){});` loop and the return in this loop is not passed to the outer function. Basically a `return true` inside the jQuery `.each` function only stops the current itteration and a return false stops the whole loop. In That case you have to save a return value outside of this loop. An example could be:

```
function checkIfEmpty() {
    var returnValue = true;
    $('#form1 input').each(function () {
        if (!$.trim(this.value).length) {
            console.log(false);
            returnValue = false;
            return false; // this stops the itteration
        } else {
            console.log(true);
            return true; // this has absolutely no effect in your case
        }
    });
    return returnValue;
}
```